# When MIDI output device callback is executed?

Tags: c#, .net, midi

I'm trying to implement working with MIDI devices in C#. At now I'm implementing sending messages via output device. I see there is the [MidiOutProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798478(v=vs.85).aspx) for it. I'm passing appropriate callback in [midiOutOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798476(v=vs.85).aspx) method. The problem is callback is not executed when I send a message via device (sending is OK, I see data was transmitted via virtual MIDI port I'm testing API on). Should I fall into this callback when message is sent? When I open a device I fall into the callback with `MOM_OPEN` message so callback is attached correctly.

I'm sending messages via [midiOutShortMsg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798481(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Updated:
It seems that for output device callback with a message will be executed only with `MOM_DONE`. From documentation on this message type:

> The MOM_DONE message is sent to a MIDI output callback function when the specified system-exclusive or stream buffer has been played and is being returned to the application.

So it seems that callback is not executed for channel messages like *Note On* sent via `midiOutShortMsg`. Is it so?

Comment: Show the code, and the message you're sending.

Comment: @CL. I've updated my question. Seems it's expected behavior...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending large MIDI messages with a buffer, the MOM_DONE callback message is needed to tell your program when it is possible to re-use (or free) the buffer. And that callback message is intended *only* for managing the buffer.

For short messages, no such notification is *necessary*. If you want to do something after you've sent a short message, just call that code directly.

Comment: Thank you for clarification!